# How to properly request location permissions for background location updates in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, background-process

I'm working on a Flutter app that needs to fetch location data in the background for both iOS and Android. I've updated my `info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml` with the necessary permissions and included the `geolocator` and `workmanager` packages. However, I'm unsure if I've set up the background fetching correctly for both platforms.

Here's how I've configured my `info.plist`:

```xml
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location information is required to validate the geo coordinates while submitting random attendance</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location information is required to validate the geo coordinates while submitting attendance</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
    <string>processing</string>
</array>
```

And for Android in AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

I've also included the geolocator and workmanager packages in my pubspec.yml:

```yaml
geolocator: ^11.0.0
workmanager: ^0.5.2
```

Here's the Dart code snippet I'm working with in `main.dart`. I'm trying to initialize a background task to fetch location updates, but I'm unsure if I've set it up correctly. Can someone review if my task initialization and callback handling are implemented properly for Flutter?

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:smartrac_blue_dart/splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import 'package:smartrac_blue_dart/database/bluedart_db.dart';
import 'locationService/locationService.dart';


// Workmanager task name
const fetchLocationTask = "fetchLocationTask";

void callbackDispatcher() {
  print('callbackDispatcher');
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    if (task == fetchLocationTask) {
      await LocationService().fetchAndStoreLocation(); // Call the static method for background execution
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Ensure Flutter is initialized
  await Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);

  // Register a periodic task
  var uniqueID = "uniqueLocationTask"; // A more static ID is recommended
  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
    uniqueID,
    fetchLocationTask,
    frequency: Duration(minutes: 2), // Adjusted to a more reasonable and platform-compliant interval
  );
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]).then((_) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  String latitude = 'Unknown';
  String longitude = 'Unknown';
  final bludartDB db_blueDart = bludartDB();
  Timer? locationTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call the web service here
    startLocationUpdates();
  }
  void startLocationUpdates() {
    print("startLocationUpdates");
    // Example of starting location updates periodically
    Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (Timer t) async {
      await LocationService().fetchAndStoreLocation();
    });
  }
  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   locationTimer?.cancel(); // Cancel the timer when the widget is disposed
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SmarTrac-BD',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Classico'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue.shade200,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On iOS you can't use a background task or timer to fetch location. You have to set up a location manager with your required location accuracy.  If you enable background location updates then your location manager delegate will receive location updates based on the accuracy you have requested, but typically every second.